# Why is the Redux store state variable a function also or did I miss something here

Tags: reactjs, redux, store, mapdispatchtoprops

I am learning React and JavaScript.

I have this Redux Store that looks like this very simple:

```
const initialState = {
  booksList: [],
  progress: false,
  faild: "",
  log: ""
};
```

When I do `mapStateToProps` to my `Component` then I don't get a `log=''` but I get something else. Basically what I try to do is this `if(log != "")`  as the image show but I get a `true` when I want to get a `false` because initial Store is empty.

As the image show the `log` also contains a function the Redux store `dispatch`.

[image]

Comment: Hi, having the full code will help us to visualize why your condition is true instead of false, thanks. By the way, you should be using this.props.log right ?

Comment: There is no "this" I dont use Rect.Component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the `log` parameter corresponds to your component properties (containing two properties `log` and `dispatch`)

You must declare your component like this :

```
function Logger({log}) {
  ...
}
```

or like this

```
function Logger(props) {
  const log = props.log;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Can I use any word like `Logger(props1)` , `Logger(bananboat)` or does it have to be `props`

Comment: `props` is just a convention, you can choose another name if you want

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, `undefined == ""` returns true.

You want to use the operators `===` and `!==` instead of `==` and `!=`.